# Keep having 'float' not subscriptable when iterating

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm trying to do some math, and for this I have to iterate through an array of floats, but for my surprise I can't. Keep having `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

```
    m = len(x)
    sx = sum(x)
    sy = sum(y)
    sxx = sum([i**2 for i in x])

    for i in range(m):
        print(i)
        sxy += sx[i]*sy[i] 
 #it should be: sxy += x[i]*y[i]
```

not familiar with python, by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sx` is a float e.g. `3.14` therefore you cannot use `sx[i]`, same with sy

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that